# Maximal ideals in the algebra of all continuously differentiable complex functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be the algebra of all continuously differentiable complex functions on the interval $[0,1]$ with pointwise multiplication, normed by

$$
||f||=||f||_{\infty} + ||f'||_{\infty}.
$$

I have to show that $A$ is a semisimple commutative Banach algebra and find its maximal ideal space.

The problem is finding its maximal ideal space.

As in example 11.13(a) of Rudin's Functional Analysis I try to prove that a maximal
ideal is given by the kernel of the complex homomorophism $h_x:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$
defined by

$$
h_x(f)=f(x).
$$
Then the union of all maximal ideals can be identified with $[0,1]$ and the intersection will be zero function from which it follows that $A$ is semisimple.

Now suppose that a maximal ideal which is not the kernel of any $h_x$ then
for every $p\in [0,1]$ there would be a $f \in M$ such that $f(p)\neq 0$. The
compactness on $[0.1]$ implies that $M$ contains finitely many functions 
$f_1, \dots f_n$ such that at least one of them is $\neq 0$ at each point of $[0,1]$. Put

$$
g=f_1\overline{f_1}, \dots f_n\overline{f_n}.
$$
If $g\in M$ this would lead to a contradiction since $g$ is invertible and proper
ideals don't contain invertible elements.

My question is why is $g\in M$ if it is, implying that it is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$, or do I have to find a different strategy.

Comment: $g=f_1\overline{f_1}+\dots+f_n\overline{f_n}$ since $M$ is an ideal ($AM\subseteq M$ and $M+M\subseteq M$).

Comment: Here is where the confusion lies for me. Why is the product of continuously differentiable complex-valued functions is also continuously differentiable. Take $z\in A$ then $\overline{z} \in A$ but the product is not continuously differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$, but is it in $[0,1]$?.

Comment: Your question is basically: why $A$ is an algebra?! In the definition of $A$ you should take real differentiability. Otherwise it is not a Banachalgebra.

Comment: Indeed it must be that the product of two complex-valued continuously differentiable function on $[0,1]$ is again continuously differentiable in order for $A$ to be an algebra, but why is this true?

Comment: Product of continuously differentiable functions $f,g$ is again differentiable and $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ is continuous, isn't it?

Comment: Yes of course, I think I got confused by f being complex valued.